# What does this Hydra error mean?

Tags: hydra

```
[ERROR] Not an Asterisk Call Manager protocol or service shutdown: 220 rblsmtpd.local
```

Above is the error I am facing while using hydra. Can somebody tell me what it means?

Comment: You might be more likely to get a satisfactory answer to your question if you provide some more information about what it is you're trying to achieve.  Specifically what are you using Hydra to do, how have you configured it, what kind of service are you testing the passwords of, that kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to attack a service that runs the [Asterisk Manager Interface](https://marcelog.github.io/articles/ami.html) (AMI) protocol. For that reason, Hydra verifies that the server returns an appropriate banner that should look similar to `Asterisk Call Manager/1.1`. If it can't identify the banner, Hydra will abort the attack.

So the error simply means that Hydra couldn't verify that the target is using the Asterisk protocol and you are possibly attacking the wrong server/port or the target uses a different protocol.

---

This is the relevant part from the source code ([`hydra-asterisk.c`](https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra/blob/f42f7626ac8af6fd678abb33677514aed9920096/hydra-asterisk.c#L103)):

```
  //banner should look like:
  //Asterisk Call Manager/1.1

  if (buf == NULL || strstr(buf, "Asterisk Call Manager/") == NULL) {
    /* check the first line */
    if (verbose || debug)
      hydra_report(stderr, "[ERROR] Not an Asterisk Call Manager protocol or service shutdown: %s\n", buf);
    hydra_child_exit(2);
  }
```